# How to use IStructuredSelection get multi selected projects?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I try to develop news eclipse tool (eclipse plugin), so I want to get multi selected projects from workspace. I try getFirstElement(), but it`s only get first selected projects.

Thank you very much

Here is some codes:

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    part = HandlerUtil.getActivePart(event);
    window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);

        selection = HandlerUtil.getActiveMenuSelection(event);

    if (selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
        IStructuredSelection structured = (IStructuredSelection)selection;

        IJavaProject project = null;

        Object elem = structured.getFirstElement();

        if (elem instanceof IJavaProject) {
            project = (IJavaProject)elem;
        } else if (elem instanceof IProject) {
            project = (IJavaProject)JavaCore.create((IProject)elem);
        }

        if (project != null) {
                        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its name suggests `IStructuredSelection.getFirstElement()` only gives you the first selection.

To get all the selections use any of the `iterator()`, `toArray()` or `toList()` methods.

For example:

```
IStructuredSelection structured = (IStructuredSelection)selection;

for (Object elem : structured.toList()) {
    IJavaProject project = null;

    if (elem instanceof IJavaProject) {
        project = (IJavaProject)elem;
    } else if (elem instanceof IProject) {
        project = (IJavaProject)JavaCore.create((IProject)elem);
    }

    if (project != null) {
       ... your code
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thank you greg-449, your example really help me a lot.